# Select returning only one element

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Maybe I'm tired but I'm not seeing why this is only returning one result. There are three Program elements under Programs but I'm only getting Excel as the result. What am I missing and why?

XML:

```
<ServerRole>
  <ServerType>Windows</ServerType>
  <Programs>
    <Program>Excel</Program>
    <Program>Outlook</Program>
    <Program>Word</Program>
  </Programs>
</ServerRole>
```

Code snippet:

```
var proggies = xlServerRoles.Descendants("ServerRole")
    .Where(prg => prg.Element("ServerType").Value == "Windows");

foreach (var prog in proggies.Descendants("Programs").Select(p => new
{
    programName = p.Element("Program").Value
}))
{
    alInstalledPrograms.Add(prog.programName.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because there is only one `Programs` in your Xml, so the loop `foreach` just loop only one time, for more corrective:

```
        foreach (var prog in proggies.Descendants("Program").Select(p => new
        {
            programName = p.Value
        }))
        {
            alInstalledPrograms.Add(prog.programName.ToString());
        }
```

You can get descendants `Program` directly in loop instead of `Programs`. For shorten approach, you don't even need loop:

```
var alInstalledPrograms = xlServerRoles.Descendants("ServerRole")
            .Where(prg => prg.Element("ServerType").Value == "Windows")
            .Descendants("Program")
            .Select(p => p.Value)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and description.

Answer (score 1):

You use `Element("Program")` where you expect *plural* `Elements`, but your loop wouldn't quite get you there as it is. Try something more like

```
var installedPrograms = (from serverRole in xlServerRoles.Descendants("ServerRole")
                         where serverRole.Element("ServerType").Value == "Windows"
                         from program in serverRole.Element("Programs").Elements("Program")
                         select program.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, between the two explanations, that really helped a lot.